# How to paste values into a certain cell by clicking on a command button

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to paste values onto a given cell is the ActiveSheet.paste the best option to do this? To rephrase this I want to paste whatever I have copied onto cell A1 by clicking on button Main() and then by clicking on button ElkhartEast () I want whatever I have copied to be in cell A300. Current Code:

```
Sub Tennessee()
    Range("A600").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub
Sub Alabama()
    Range("A900").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub
Sub Main()
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub
Sub NorthCarolina()
    Range("A1200").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste

End Sub
Sub Pennsylvania()
    Range("A1500").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub
Sub Texas()
    Range("A1800").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub
Sub WestCoast()
    Range("A2100").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub

Sub ElkhartEast()
    Range("A300").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `.Select` and `.Paste` is not correct vba coding practice.

The following code makes use of `String` or `Integer` (depending on what you need) to hold the value and place it in the specific `Cell`.

```
Option Explicit
'If you need a number value then Integer
Dim intValue as Integer
'If you need a text value then String
Dim strValue as Integer

'As example I will use Integer
Sub Main()
   IntValue = Range("A1").Value
End Sub

Sub NorthCarolina()
   Range("A1200").Value = IntValue
End Sub

Sub Pennsylvania()
   Range("A1500").Value = IntValue
End Sub

Sub Texas()
   Range("A1800").Value = IntValue
End Sub
Sub WestCoast()
   Range("A2100").Value = IntValue
End Sub

Sub ElkhartEast()
   Range("A300").Value = IntValue
End Sub

Sub Tennessee()
   Range("A600").Value = IntValue
End Sub

Sub Alabama()
   Range("A900").Value = IntValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A600").Select` will just select the cell. To paste the value, we need to first copy the value from the cell. `.Select` will not copy the value as such but will just set the focus on the respective cell.
And `ActiveSheet.Paste` will paste the value (if at all copied) into the cell where the focus is currently set. This can be very arbitrary if we don't focus on where we click on the worksheet

Instead the below code would help:

```
Sub Tennessee()
        Range("A1").Copy
        Range("A2").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```